# Speech Recogonition as an background service Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, speech-recognition

I am developing an speech recognition system in android . I have succeeded in it . But the Google Voice Dialog box keeps annoying me and i want to get rid off that . i.e I want to Run this voice recognition in the background as an service . I know there are many SO posts on this with answers . But my problem is the every code here is on Native java and i develop on phone gap . SO i am not able to port this thing to phone gap . I have my code below . So , Any help would be appreciated ! And i use [this](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer) plugin on phone gap . Thanks in advance .

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.speech;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

/**
 * Style and such borrowed from the TTS and PhoneListener plugins
 */
public class SpeechRecognizer extends CordovaPlugin {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = SpeechRecognizer.class.getSimpleName();
    private static int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;
    private LanguageDetailsChecker languageDetailsChecker;

    //@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        Boolean isValidAction = true;

        this.callbackContext= callbackContext;

        // Action selector
        if ("startRecognize".equals(action)) {
            // recognize speech
            startSpeechRecognitionActivity(args);
        } else if ("getSupportedLanguages".equals(action)) {
            getSupportedLanguages();
        } else {
            // Invalid action
            this.callbackContext.error("Unknown action: " + action);
            isValidAction = false;
        }

        return isValidAction;

    }

    // Get the list of supported languages
    private void getSupportedLanguages() {
        if (languageDetailsChecker == null){
            languageDetailsChecker = new LanguageDetailsChecker(callbackContext);
        }
        // Create and launch get languages intent
        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
        cordova.getActivity().sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, languageDetailsChecker, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);

    }

    /**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     *
     * @param args Argument array with the following string args: [req code][number of matches][prompt string]
     */
    private void startSpeechRecognitionActivity(JSONArray args) {
        int maxMatches = 0;
        String prompt = "";
        String language = Locale.getDefault().toString();

        try {
            if (args.length() > 0) {
                // Maximum number of matches, 0 means the recognizer decides
                String temp = args.getString(0);
                maxMatches = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            }
            if (args.length() > 1) {
                // Optional text prompt
                prompt = args.getString(1);
            }
            if (args.length() > 2) {
                // Optional language specified
                language = args.getString(2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.format("startSpeechRecognitionActivity exception: %s", e.toString()));
        }

        // Create the intent and set parameters
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);

        if (maxMatches > 0)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, maxMatches);
        if (!prompt.equals(""))
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, prompt);

        cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            returnSpeechResults(matches);
        }
        else {
            // Failure - Let the caller know
            this.callbackContext.error(Integer.toString(resultCode));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void returnSpeechResults(ArrayList<String> matches) {
        JSONArray jsonMatches = new JSONArray(matches);
        this.callbackContext.success(jsonMatches);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your need is a little different than the functionality provided by the plugin, it seems that you would need to [write your own plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html). You can of course use the plugin sources (especially [plugin.xml](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer/blob/master/plugin.xml), [SpeechRecognizer.js](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer/blob/master/SpeechRecognizer.js) and [SpeechRecognizer.java](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer/blob/master/SpeechRecognizer.java)) as an example how to implement it in general.

Comment: Yea i am fine with writing the plugin . But my problem is to modifiy SpeechRecognizer .  As i not so popular with Java